# What is the Alternative of PictureBox in Silverlight?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, silverlight, picturebox

i have a PictureBox in my Windows Form application and i am in the process of converting my application to Silverlight and i would like to know what is the alternative of PictureBox in Silverlight, Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you might want to try is the [Viewbox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.viewbox%28v=vs.96%29.aspx) control. Then, inside of the Viewbox you can place an image. The great thing about the Viewbox is that you can always scale everything inside consistently, even as the VB resizes. Or, you can use the Image as @Chris pointed out and provided size limits and a scale setting.

Sample XAML:

```
<Viewbox x:Name="vb">
    <Image x:Name="myImage" Source="pathToImage"/>
</Viewbox>
```

You could then place the Viewbox inside a Stackpanel or Grid to achieve proper layout. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the functionality of the PictureBox you are using, you could just use the [Image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image%28VS.95%29.aspx) control in Silverlight.

Answer (score 1):

Image control is your only choice for this case, but you should be careful that this control just support .jpg and .png image extentions and for other formats you must create or use converters